# How can I show the points of continuity of the following function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

How can I show the points of continuity of the following function

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x,  & \text{if $x \in \Bbb Q$} \\[2ex]
x+3, & \text{if $x \in \Bbb I$ }
\end{cases}$$

I am having problems trying to solve this kind of exercise
:C

Comment: you want to show it is discontinuous, right?

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is continuous at $x$ if $f(x)$ is the limit of $f(x_n)$ if $(x_n)$ converges towards $x$. Suppose that $x$ is rational, $x$ is a limit of irrational $(x_n)$, so $lim_n x_n+3=2x$ which implies $2x=x+3$ and $x=3$.

Suppose that $x$ is irrational, it is the limit of the sequence of rational $(x_n)$ so $x+3=2x_n$ and $x+3=2x$, $x=3$ impossible.

So $f$ is only continuous at $3$.